# Airflow : Complete all tasks in a TaskGroup before running to the next one and avoid dependancies between TaskGroup

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-2.x, orchestration, airflow-taskflow

I would like to set up a DAG where all tasks in a single TaskGroup are done before running to the next one.
Meaning that in the example (cf screenshot), the `Workflow_FRA` has to be done with the tasks `run_task_FRA` and `run_next_task_FRA` then the `Workflow_BEL` would run and on and on.

Below the DAG script but it's running the tasks in parallel regardless the TaskGroup.

[image]

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow import DAG

with DAG(
        dag_id="dev_dag",
        concurrency=1,
        start_date=datetime(2024, 2, 27),
        schedule_interval='*/1 * * * *',
        catchup=False
) as dag:

    @task(task_id="start_task")
    def start_task():
        print("start")

    start_task = start_task()

    @task(task_id="end_task")
    def end_task():
        print("end")

    end_task = end_task()

    for country in ["FR", "BE", "SP", "EN"]:
        with TaskGroup(group_id=f"workflow_{country}") as workflow:
            @task(task_id=f"run_task_{country}")
            def run_task():
                time.sleep(5)
                print("run task")


            @task(task_id=f"run_next_task_{country}")
            def run_next_task():
                time.sleep(5)
                print("run next task")

            start_task >> run_task() >> run_next_task() >> end_task
    start_task >> workflow >> end_task
```

What I want to achieve it's, if the TaskGroup workflow_BE fails, the next TaskGroup worflows are able to run and I'd like to clear the tasks from the one that has failed without running the next taskgroups again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `chain` operator:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain
from airflow import DAG

with DAG(
        dag_id="dev_dag",
        concurrency=1,
        start_date=datetime(2024, 2, 27),
        schedule_interval=None,
        catchup=False
) as dag:

    @task(task_id="start_task")
    def start_task():
        print("start")

    start_task = start_task()

    @task(task_id="end_task")
    def end_task():
        print("end")

    end_task = end_task()

    tasks = [start_task]
    for country in ["FR", "BE", "SP", "EN"]:
        with TaskGroup(group_id=f"workflow_{country}") as workflow:
            @task(task_id=f"run_task_{country}")
            def run_task():
                time.sleep(5)
                print("run task")


            @task(
                task_id=f"run_next_task_{country}",
                trigger_rule="all_done"
            )
            def run_next_task():
                time.sleep(5)
                print("run next task")

            start_task >> run_task() >> run_next_task() >> end_task
        tasks.append(workflow)
    tasks.append(end_task)
    chain(*tasks)
```

The dependency graph will look like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply !
If the TaskGroup workflow_BE fails, the next workflows won't be running how can I manage that ? knowing that if workflow_BE fails and the other are able to run, I'd like to clear the tasks from workflow_BE without running the next taskgroups again

Comment: @AntoineF that can be achieved through proper `trigger_rule` for tasks. If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you need to add a `trigger_rule = 'all_done` to the `run_next_task` tasks. This way the dag doesn't stop if a `run_task` task fails.

Comment: But how I could trigger only one country without running the downstream taskgroups ?

Comment: When you're clearing the status for the failed task, make sure you turn off the Recursive option so the statuses for downstream tasks are not cleared.

Comment: It totally works for me ! Thanks @ARCrow